# Matlab - numerical solution system of ode

Tags: matlab, ode, runge-kutta

I want to solve the following system of differntial equations in matlab with my own runge kutty method:

 $\frac{dx_{1}{dt}$  = $x_{2}$

 $\frac{dx_{2}{dt}$ = A $x_{1} + B $x_{2}$ + a*sin(C*t) 

 I wrote

```
function xdot = NaszModel(x, aa, bb, AA, BB, CC)

  a= aa;
  A = AA;
  B = BB;
  C = CC;

  xdot = [ x(2) 
           A*x(1) - B*x(2) + a*sin(C)];
end

function [x, t] = RK(f, x0, t0, T, h)

   t = t0:h:T; 
   nt = numel(t);
   nx = numel(x0);


   x = nan(nx, nt);

   x(:,1) = x0;

   for k = 1:nt-1

     k1 = h*f(t(k), x(:,k));
     k2 = h*f(t(k) + h/3 ,  x(:,k) + h/3 ); 
     k3 = h*f(t(k) + (2*h)/3, x(:,k) - k1/3 + k2);
     k4 = h*f(t(k) + h, x(:,k) + k1 - k2 + k3);

     dx = (k1 + 3*k2 + 3*k3 + k4)/8;

     x(:,k+1) = x(:,k) + dx;


   end
end

a = 1;
A = 0.1;
B = 0.1;
C = 1;

f = @(t,x) NaszModel(x, a, b, A, B, C);
x0 = [1, 0];
t0 = 0;
T = 100;
h = 1;

[x, t] = RK(f, x0, t0, T, h);

plot(t,x);
legend('x', 'v');


plot(x(1,:), x(2,:));
xlabel('x');
ylabel('v(x)');
```

Everything works fine, but when im trying to add t to sin, i mean: i have in my solution a*sin(C), but i have to solve eqution with a*sin(C*t). `

how it should be written to make it works also for a*sin(C*t)?

Comment: You need to pass `t` also to the model function, then you can also use it in the ODE.

Comment: when i add here:
 xdot = [ x(2) 
           A*x(1) - B*x(2) + a*sin(C*t)];
like that i have errors

Comment: You need to change the interface of the function, so that `t` is actually passed along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `t` also to the model function, then you can also use it in the ODE. This means that you need to change the interface of the function.

```matlab
function xdot = NaszModel(t, x, a, b, A, B, C)
  xdot = [ x(2) 
        A*x(1) - B*x(2) + a*sin(C*t)];
end

f = @(t,x) NaszModel(t, x, a, b, A, B, C);
```

Comment: and do you know how can i get derivative of solution after a ?
because normal diff doesnt work

Comment: I do not understand, the solution of a differential equation is integration. Where did you get differentiation involved?

Comment: i mean: dx(1)/da and dx(2)/da (d - derivative)

Comment: If you name those derivatives `u`, then `du(1)/dt=u(2)` and `du(2)/dt = A*u(1)-B*u(2)+sin(C*t)`, so by enlarging the system for these two components you can compute their values simultaneously (or you could solve that separately, as there is no non-linear terms to provide a coupling).

Comment: but you wrote derivatives after t and i have to find after a (parameter)

Comment: Yes, `u=dx/da`. Then apply the commutativity of partial derivatives to `du/dt`.

Comment: so for exmaple i tried first find dx(1)/dB and dx(2)/dB and i get dx(1)/dB = t and dx(2)/dB = integrate (from 0 to t) v e^t ds.
I dont know how solve that? and how do it in matlab?

Comment: Similarly, set `v=dx/dB` to get `dv(1)/dt=v(2)` and `dv(2)/dt=A*v(1)+B*v(2)+x(2)` so that here you get a coupling to the original solution.

Comment: i dont see it. I dont understand how i get solution now. 
Can i ask you to write more please ?

Comment: See my answer to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698725/derivative-after-parameter-system-of-ode